# Postgres View slow performance

Tags: performance, postgresql, view, comparison

My question is related to slow performance of a Postgres view. I've just spent few hours with this issue and now I'm totally out of ideas.

I have created view which can dynamically calculate data based on several tables, view itself has acceptable performance until one specific condition is used.

Name of view is `RV_Replenish` and most important column is `QtyToOrder`, which is dynamically calculated based on some other tables.

Very strange for me are next two queries:

```
1. select count(*) from rv_replenish
   where (case when qtytoorder>0 then 1 else 0 end)>0

2. select count(*) from rv_replenish
   where (case when qtytoorder>0 then 1 else 0 end)=1
```

Execution of second query is 10 times slower than first one, but returned number is same. What can be the reason? Reason can be related maybe to setup of postgres server, because I tested it on local and production development. On local development is execution of both queries same, but production server executes second variant very slowly.

Comment: What is wrong with `select count(*) from rv_replenish where qtytoorder > 0;`

Comment: Why do you write a where condition like this? And did you create an index on this column? Could you show us the results from EXPLAIN ANALYZE?

Comment: Hi, first of all, thanks for reply... condition is just an example...My goal is to create column in mentioned view like `case when qtytoorder>0 then 'R' end as parameterX`...Column parameterX with string value is needed for framework using this view (string column  can be used as filter in reports)...

Comment: I will post result of explain analyze in few hours...but I am wondering why is this behavious so strange? Comparison to QtyToOrder is quite fast but comparison with where CASE is used CASE is slower... Important is that qtyToOrder is dynamicaly calculated in view, its not column of table...at the end, I suppose that index coldnt be the problem because comparison direct to QtyToOrder is fast..

Comment: `select count(*) from rv_replenish where showproducts='REP'` takes  (30sec)
`select count(*) from rv_replenish where qtyToOrder>0` takes  (3sec)

Column ShowProducts its nothing more than `CASE WHEN mquery.qtytoorder > 0 THEN 'REP' ELSE NULL END AS showproducts`

That's the reason why I'm wondering why comparison to `showProducts` column is so slow..